# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : on chrome and "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code is:

```
function getCategoryResponse() {
    var appid = "1";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/genres?id=36&callback=myCallbackFunction',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            var appData = data.results[0]; //get first record from array            
            console.log(appData);
            return;
        },
        error: function () {
            //alert('something bad happened');
            console.log("something bad happened");
        }
    });
}
```

It results in:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" /* on chrome  */

"SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" /* on firefox */
```

Comment: When asking for help, please be courteous and format your code using some reasonable, consistent indentation.

Comment: Try to use http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php to check your syntax

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link for checking syntax.

Answer (score 3):

That URL doesn't return a JSONP response, just a JSON response that starts like this:

```
{
    "36": {
        "name": "App Store",
        "id": "36",
        "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8",
        "rssUrls": {
            "topAppsByRevenue": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topappsbyrevenue/genre=36/json",
            "topPaidIpadApplications": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppaidipadapplications/genre=36/json",
            "topIpadAppsByRevenue": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topipadappsbyrevenue/genre=36/json",
            "topFreeIpadApplications": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeipadapplications/genre=36/json",
```

You'll have to consult the documentation to find out how to tell it you need JSONP, which would start like this:

```
myCallbackFunction({
    "36": {
        "name": "App Store",
        "id": "36",
        "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8",
        "rssUrls": {
            "topAppsByRevenue": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topappsbyrevenue/genre=36/json",
            "topPaidIpadApplications": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppaidipadapplications/genre=36/json",
            "topIpadAppsByRevenue": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topipadappsbyrevenue/genre=36/json",
            "topFreeIpadApplications": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeipadapplications/genre=36/json",
```

Separately: When using jQuery, it's best to allow jQuery to specify the name of the callback function rather than specifying it yourself.

Comment: when i am using onlu json like : 

url: 'http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/genres?id=36',
data: {},
dataType: 'json',

its give error like:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/genres?id=36. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: i am new to JavaScript: please help me to parse this URL:
http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/genres?id=36
Thanks

Comment: @NaeemParacha: Right, the reason you're getting that error using `dataType: 'json'` is that then you're using a normal XMLHttpRequest, and those are controlled by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You were probably right to use JSONP, you just need to consult the documentation for the Apple API you're using to find out how to tell it you need a JSONP response. (Assuming it supports JSONP.)

Comment: same code with this URL working fine.. 
url: 'http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=661678191&country=AE&callback=myCallbackFunction'

Comment: @NaeemParacha: I told you: Tell the API you need JSONP, not JSON.

Comment: its third party API and its not changeable.

Comment: @NaeemParacha: I didn't say you had to change the API. You have to pass it a parameter telling it you need JSONP, assuming it supports JSONP. If it doesn't support JSONP, then since this is a cross-domain request, unless they support CORS (see the link above re SOP), you can't request that info using the browser. You'll have to use a server as a proxy. Read up on the details of what JSON, JSONP, the SOP, CORS, and ajax are and you'll have a much better idea what's going on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51341/discussion-between-naeem-paracha-and-t-j-crowder)